# Python/sklearn - preprocessing.MinMaxScaler 1d deprecation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'd like to scale a column of a dataframe to have values between 0 and 1. For this I'm using a `MinMaxScaler`, which works fine, but is sending me mixed messages. I'm doing:

```
x = df['Activity'].values #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df['Activity'] = pd.Series(x_scaled)
```

Message numero uno for this code is a warning:

`DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.`

Okay, so apparentyl having 1d arrays is gonna be a no-no soon, so let's try to reshape it as advised:

```
x = df['Activity'].values.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Now the code doesn't even run: `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional` is thrown. So I'm confused. 1d is going to be deprecated soon, but the data also has to be 1d?? How to do this safely? What's the issue here?

**EDIT as requested by @sascha**

`x` looks like this:

```
array([ 0.00568953,  0.00634314,  0.00718003, ...,  0.01976002,
        0.00575024,  0.00183782])
```

And after reshaping:

```
array([[ 0.00568953],
       [ 0.00634314],
       [ 0.00718003],
       ..., 
       [ 0.01976002],
       [ 0.00575024],
       [ 0.00183782]])
```

The whole warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py:321: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  warnings.warn(DEPRECATION_MSG_1D, DeprecationWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py:356: DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
  warnings.warn(DEPRECATION_MSG_1D, DeprecationWarning)
```

The error when I reshape:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-df180aae2d1a> in <module>()
      2 min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
      3 x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
----> 4 telecom['Activity'] = pd.Series(x_scaled)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    225             else:
    226                 data = _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy,
--> 227                                        raise_cast_failure=True)
    228 
    229                 data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
   2918     elif subarr.ndim > 1:
   2919         if isinstance(data, np.ndarray):
-> 2920             raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional')
   2921         else:
   2922             subarr = _asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)

Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Comment: Show the shape of x before and after reshaping. Also read the docs about the desired array-form. There will always be one-dimensional-like inputs, but they need to be presented as one row for example (the 1 sample case; so that shape actually is 2).

Comment: @sascha Updated the question as requested.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is not part of the pd.Series() line which would be no surprise. I really don't understand why people don't post the whole stack-trace/error... So much information is lost by only showing the error itself without any more context.

Comment: @sascha Added the whole error to the question.

Comment: You did not show any error. What you added is (1) Just a bunch of warnings (2) Not the whole stack-trace (where is your ```Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional```). Well good luck. I think i already told you the reason for a possible error, but well...

Comment: Now you added all of that stack-trace: you see that i was right guessing the problem and it's even telling you exactly what's the problem. Hint: it has nothing to do with sklearn. Hint2: You want to build a **series** by using the data-format of sklearn which is **not a series-like** format.

Comment: Strange that it won't work on 1d arrays it seems a natural use-case.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simply drop `pd.Series`:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
df = pd.DataFrame({'Activity': [ 0.00568953,  0.00634314,  0.00718003, 
                                0.01976002, 0.00575024,  0.00183782]})
x = df['Activity'].values.reshape(-1, 1) #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
df['Activity'] = x_scaled
```

or you can explicitly get the first column of `x_scaled`:

```
df['Activity'] = pd.Series(x_scaled[:, 0])
```